# How to exit interpreter I need to start from the shell?

Tags: bash, r

I'm using R with kdb+/q. In order to access our data in kdb, there needs to be a running q process in the background on some port. What we usually do is run the command `q -p 5000 &` to initialize a q process and then we exit out of the q interpreter. The problem we are running into is that we cannot programmatically kill and start q processes. For instance, we sometimes need to reset the connection, so we would run `killall -9 q` and then type the command `q -p 5000 &` and then type `\\` to exit the q interpreter.

But trying to pass these system commands through R ends up throwing all sorts of errors. To try and start a q process without needing to manually type `\\` to exist q, I tried `printf '\\\\' | q -p 5000 &` (and a few variants of this command), but I had no luck.

Comment: Is not clear for me what you are asking, could you reformulate and add some source links? Exactly which steps did you do, what you expect, what happen instead? Why the `-9`? Why sending to background (`&`)?

Comment: According to this article, it should be possible to daemonize `q` non-interactively using input redirection + nohup: https://code.kx.com/v2/kb/daemon/

Comment: @PabloA Not sure why my colleague adds the -9 to the kill q command to be honest. Sending the command to the background lets us set up other stuff in the R script while the q process starts up.

Comment: If you found it please answer your own question with the complete explanation.

Comment: @PabloA I will, just going to test it out the interaction with R/rkdb more carefully first.

Answer (score 0):

https://code.kx.com/v2/kb/daemon/

This works. In R I call:

```
system("nohup q -p 5000 < /dev/null > /tmp/stdoe 2>&1&")
Sys.sleep(3)
kdb_conn <- rkdb::open_connection('localhost', 5000)
```